# ImageJ Java 16 Bit Grayscale Stack to RGB-Image

Tags: java, image-processing, plugins, imagej, 16-bit

I have searched for a long time but found nothing.
I'm writing a java plugin for ImageJ to process raw-images, which should realize a complete pipeline(debayer, tonemapper,ccm..). For now it is about 16 bit input images, because I still have difficulties with 32 bit processing in ImageJ.

Currently I have a stack of three 16 bit grayscale images for red, green and blue. I am currently failing to merge these three images to the final color image. The color-processor only gives me an 8 bit output image. But I want to cover the complete 16 bits.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Classic RGB images made from an R, G and B channel are 24 bit. That is only 8 bits of R, G, and B though. You can't cover the complete 16 bits. You just have to drop the least significant 8 bits from each 16-bit value and use the remainder.

Comment: The pipeline will be used to process HDR images. HDR and 8 bits do not really fit together. Is there really no other way?